# How to direct gnu readline away from stdout

Tags: c, stdin, gnu, readline, getline

So I wanted to make a program that accepts input from `stdin` through re-direction or interactive input.  `getline` can achieve the re-direction read, but I wanted to have all the nice features of `readline` for the interactive input.  The program's purpose is to manipulate text through a language and output the results to stdout (similar to what sed does).  The issue, is that I cannot do `my_prog > output.txt` with `readline` because whatever was entered into `readline` the output of readline goes into that file, and I cannot even see it.  Currently, I have a workaround where I just send the output of `readline` to `stderr` using `rl_outstream`.  This gives me the behavior I am looking for, but feels like a hack when there is probably a more straight-forward solution.  A good example of what I am looking for is what python does.

```sh
python > output.txt
>>> print 'hello'
>>> exit()
cat output.txt
hello
```

Here is some code to demonstrate what I'm doing...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "readline/readline.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* from_stdin = malloc(512);
    char* line = NULL;

    rl_outstream = stderr;

    if(isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
        do {
            line = readline("");
            if(line) {
                strcat(from_stdin, line);
                strcat(from_stdin, "\n");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while(1);
    } else {
        size_t n = 0;
        while(getline(&line, &n, stdin) != -1)
            strcat(from_stdin, line);
    }
    puts(from_stdin);
}
```

Patch for accepted solution:

```c
--rl_outstream = stderr;
++FILE* more_hacky = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");
++rl_outstream = more_hacky;
```

I agree about this being more hacky.  I will probably leave my code as is, but this would leave stderr more "pure" for errors if I choose.

Comment: **bash(1)** contains the same code -- `rl_outstream = stderr;`, in its `bashline.c` function `initialize_readline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it is worth, CPython **does** use `STDERR_FILENO` as the output file descriptor for Readline iff `!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)` a fact which you can verify with `strace` and alike.

Without redirection we get

```
% strace -o strace.out python3 && grep '>>>' strace.out
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
write(1, ">>> ", 4)                     = 4
```

and with redirection

```
% strace -o strace.out python3 > python.out && grep '>>>' strace.out
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
write(2, ">>> ", 4)                     = 4
```

---

The alternative would be opening `/dev/tty` for the output stream but I feel that *that* would be more, not less, hacky.

Comment: Yeah, I was just playing with it some more, and saw that if I do `python > out.txt 2> err.txt`, all the Python header information and the `>>>` go to err.txt.  The code that I write, however, prints to the terminal and does not write to either file.